# display .raw image in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, display, raw-data

I have MATLAB code to read raw data and I can display it using `'uint16'` like this:

[image: image with using unsigned integer 16]

But when I try to change `'uint16'` to `'uint64'` I get this:

[image: image with using unsigned integer 64]

I want to display my image like the 16bit image with using 64bit. Is there a way to do that? My code is here:

```
clear all;
I=fopen('data.raw');
A=fread(I,[2048 1536],'uint16');

imagesc(A.');
newmap = contrast(A);
colormap(newmap)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself why do I want to use 64-bit ? A color is generally RGB888, 8-bits per components ... you can read the image in uint16 and then use this data in 64-bit  floating point (double) format ... is that what you are trying to do ?

Comment: because i chose the data type as unsigned 64 in ENVI. so i want to compare both images in same conditions. sorry if i couldn't express properly but the point is i get very high quality image with ENVI but when i display in matlab with uint16 the image's quality is too bad. i thought that i can get the same good image with Matlab too.